# Maven WAR dependency with maven-war-plugin - conflicts with eclipse builds

Tags: maven, war

I have a war that contains java code - and need to make other code dependent on the code contained in the war.
I have read elsewhere about using

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That works fine.
I build the original war and a new jar

```
search-classes.jar
search.war
```

The project can be compiled in two ways (1) on the command line with mvn (2) in eclipse as a standard project (NOT a maven project) - this how my company does it!

Hence, i am compiling with eclipse:eclipse on the mvn command line, but this make the original project now dependent upon itself in the eclipse .classpath file.

That is the .classpath file for the project search-war now contains the line

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/search-war"/>
```

I need to edit this manually (in eclipse) after every maven build. 
Is there any way to fix this?

```
Solution:

There is a bug in the eclipse plugin.
But it only shows up under specific conditions...
The war was being renamed using the build/fileName tags. 
When i disabled this - the problem disappeared - and all is fine.
(I just renamed the war in a post-build shell script instead).
```

Comment: Your company is following a custom process that almost everybody else thinks is highly inefficient, expensive, and prone to errors. The only people who don't feel this way are also doing it wrong. Use maven, follow its processes, and flourish, then demonstrate this goodness to your fellow programmers and leaders, and hopefully they'll learn and follow your lead.

Answer (score 1):

Not without splitting the project, i.e. create a separate module for the code (which creates only a jar file) and set it as dependency in your war as well as any other project that requires it.

It is much cleaner that way, works using `eclipse:eclipse` as well as m2e and has no subtile problems in a multimodule build (for example when only running `mvn compile` which does not work as expected using attached artifacts).

As a general rule: do not use attached artifacts (with classifiers) for code.